# How to enable/disable authentication without password when executing commands as superuser?

Tags: linux, fedora

On a Fedora 19 system which I set up for somebody a while ago I noticed that no authentication is required when commands are executed as the superuser. So, for example, when running Yum Extender, configuring the firewall or running some command with sudo in the terminal, I am not asked to provide a password. (With graphical applications the authentication dialog pops up for a few milliseconds.) For better security I would like to disable this automatic (authentication-less) assumption of superuser privileges. I do not remember if or how I enabled this authentication without a password. I might have enabled it for convenience for the non-pro user of this machine, but did not do any "fancy" things (like editing config files) to do so. I did not edit the sudoer file. I just checked that. I might have checked a "Do not ask for password again" checkbox or something similar. Whatever I did, I would like to undo it and enforce authentication for superuser tasks again.

Comment: Possibly stupid question... These users with `sudo` permission _do_ have passwords, right? It's just that `sudo` isn't prompting for them?

Comment: There is one user. And this user has a password. The problem is that the user is not prompted for a password in the situations I described. (For login a password must be entered.)

Comment: Are they a member of the `wheel` group?

Comment: The **id** command will give you the group membership of an user: `id [USERNAME]`.

Answer (score 0):

Type `man sudoers`.  Look for `NOPASSWD` and `timeout` on the man page for clues.

Answer (score 0):

The user most likely has the NOPASSWD Tag_Spec set in [/etc/sudoers](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) (if that link dies, it was just a link to the result of running `man 5 sudoers` on a normal Linux system).
You'll want to remove or comment out (by putting a '#' at the beginning of the line) the line(s) pertaining to that user's NOPASSWD status.

If no such line exists, it's possible the user has a ridiculously long timeout between authentications, in which case grep for `passwd_timeout`; if that value is set to 0 then timeout is unlimited, but otherwise the timeout is in minutes and indicates how long the user can continue using `sudo` after an initial authenticated use before authenticating again.

The user may also be in the `wheel` group (as turned out to be the case).

Comment: In the /etc/sudoers file there is no user with NOPASSWD set. A long timeout can't be the reason, since the user is not even prompted for the first time for a password. And, as I said, it is not just sudo that does not prompt for a password. This problem is not specific to sudo.

Comment: I admit I'd assumed that the other applications were using `sudo` under the hood, although they might be using `su`... In any case, I'll check `su` and get back to you.

Comment: What groups are they in? If they're a member of the `wheel` group, that might be the issue. (You can find out by running the `groups` command)

Comment: The user is in the wheel group. I have no idea how that happened. I removed the user from this group. Now graphical applications which require superuser privileges prompt for a password again, as they should do. But there is a new problem with sudo. When trying to execute a command with sudo, I get this error message: "xyz is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported." (xyz is the user name) Is it reasonable to assume the system has been compromised by some attacker?

Comment: Clarification for my last question: I ask this because I never made such far reaching and stupid changes to the system and I am sure the unexperienced user of the machine did not either.